# How can I upload a zip file using nodejs and extract it?

Tags: node.js, zip

I want to upload a zip file into the server using node.So can any one help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First upload your zip file using Multer:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/tmp/my-uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

Then unzip it using unzipper module:

1) Install unzipper module

```
npm i unzipper
```

2) ExtractZip.js JavaScript

```
const unzipper = require('./unzip');
var fs = require('fs');


fs.createReadStream('path/to/archive.zip')
  .pipe(unzipper.Parse())
  .on('entry', function (entry) {
    const fileName = entry.path;
    const type = entry.type; // 'Directory' or 'File'
    const size = entry.vars.uncompressedSize; // There is also compressedSize;
    if (fileName === "this IS the file I'm looking for") {
      entry.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output/path'));
    } else {
      entry.autodrain();
    }
  });
```

// [Source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzipper)

Test:

```
c:\Samim>node ExtractZip.js
```

Comment: Thank you samim for your response. But when i'm using fs ,i'm getting this error ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
[SERVER]     at fs.js:35:5

Comment: Please check with unzipper module.

Comment: @Samim do you always have to temporarily put the contents into a temporary folder before unzipping?

Comment: Works great for me. Just one minor correction:
const unzipper = require('./unzip'); should be:
const unzipper = require('unzipper');

Answer (score 0):

You can try multer
`npm install --save multer`

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/tmp/my-uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```